# merge git projects without common commit

Tags: git

right now i have several projects tracked with git. Now, i want to make one big project, with several subfolders for each of the previous projects and preserve their history along with the history of the big project.

So basically what i have now is

```
projecta/
projectb/
projectc/
bigproject/
```

And what i want is

```
bigproject/
    projecta/
    projectb/
    projectc/
```

Is that even possible without losing history?

Cheers

Comment: Not really the intended use case for Git. Git works best with sane content boundaries, one project per repo.

Comment: after merging the repos it would be one big project, though the "imported" versions should be visible as well

Comment: [Git Subtree Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html)

Comment: Does your `bigproject/` path contain anything yet, or is it just a placeholder to receive the incoming `projectA`, `projectB`, `projectC` folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
#Preparing the repos: moving files in subdirectories
cd projecta
mkdir projecta
git mv file1 file2 dir1 dir2 projecta 
git commit -am "Moved file"
#Do it for each other repos

#Actually merging
git clone url_to_projecta bigproject
cd bigproject
git remote add b url_to_projectb
git remote add c url_to_projectc
git fetch --all
git merge b/master
git merge c/master
```

---

In plain English: You can merge Git trees even if they have nothing in common, so you just have to:

- go in one of your repos
- fetch the others (you now have several trees with no commits in common)
- create merge-commits, to merge those trees

That's it.

And if you want to have a filesystem which looks like:

```
bigproject/
  projecta/
  projectb/
  projectc/
```

the easiest is to deal with it first

Comment: IIRC `git merge` won't let you so easily merge branches with no common history.  (at least it didn't when I had my big case of needing it, I ended up doing very ugly things with `git filter-branch` to work aroudn it)

Comment: I've never had issues with this. What kind of errors did you have when you tried such a merge?

Comment: Off the top of my head, something as simple as “no common ancestor”. If I have time, I'll try and give it a look again tomorrow morning.

Comment: Good to read. One less use-case that'll require tricky rewrites and visible plumbing. Thanks for making me notice!

Answer (score 0):

If your are ok with maintaining 4 repos, I think this is a perfect case for using [git-submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

In case you want to merge them into a single repo only, you can probably use each of these as a branch on a new repo, and then merge them all into one repo.

### Sample instructions for 2 repos

Repository setup (will create two repos, one is in `proj/p1/p1`, other in `proj/p2/p2`)

```
mkdir -p proj/p1/p1 proj/p2/p2 proj/merged
touch proj/p1/p1/f1 proj/p1/p1/f2 proj/p2/p2/f3
cd proj/p1/p1/ && git init && git add . && git commit -m "proj 1" && cd ../..
cd p2/p2/ && git init && git add . && git commit -m "proj 2" && cd ../..
```

We now move all code in repo `p1` to a folder named `p1` within it

```
cd p1/p1/ && git rm -r --cached "*" && cd ..
mv p1/.git . && git add . && git commit -m "moved" && cd ..
```

We next move all code in repo `p2` to a folder named `p2` within it

```
cd p2/p2/ && git rm -r --cached "*" && cd ..
mv p2/.git . && git add . && git commit -m "moved" && cd ..
```

We now initialize a completely new repo `merged` to have all the merged code

```
cd merged && git init && touch f4 && git add . && git commit -m "init" && cd ..
```

And add this new merged code as a remote to both `p1`, `p2` and push the respective code from master branch as project names to the remote

```
cd p1 && git remote add merged ../merged/ && git push merged master:p1 && cd ..
cd p2 && git remote add merged ../merged/ && git push merged master:p2 && cd ..
```

We can now go to the newly initialized repo and merge branches `p1`, `p2`

```
cd merged && git merge p1 && git merge p2
```

And we are done. A simple `gitk` or a `git log --pretty --oneline`  will reveal all commits to you.